# Construction next door damaged our fence, what can I do?

Tags: property, florida

Several months back construction started in the empty lot next door. They essentially built a house there, and in the process dug up a lot of dirt and gravel. The construction workers dumped this gravel on the border between their working area and my back yard fence, causing the fence to collapse and spilling gravel into our property.

We were told by the construction manager that a fence would be built, but no action has been taken so far as they are not finished. Not only did they cause property damage to us, but we've had to keep our dogs inside most of the time because they can now very easily escape our yard through that collapsed fence.

What legal action can I take to remedy this situation? Would I be able to pressure the company into building the fence earlier because of the damage? Can I get compensation?

This is in the state of Florida.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have suffered property and other damages from the actions of another party.  The most common remedies pursued include:

1. Negotiating a resolution with the party
2. Negotiating a resolution with the party's insurer, if they have one
3. Filing a claim with your insurer (who might then seek reimbursement from the other party)
4. Suing the party in [small-claims-court](/questions/tagged/small-claims-court)
5. Engaging an attorney to seek other legal remedies